# How to perform a fast array multiplication?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, assembly, matrix-multiplication

I have two array with the same size:

```
A = [a1, a2, a3]
B = [b1; b2; b3]
```

I need to perform an array multiplication in order to build the following matrix:

```
            |a1|
M = A * B = |a2| * |b1 b2 b3|  //M31 * M13 ==> M33 and M13 * M31 ==> M11.  Mnk: Matrix with n lines and k columns.
            |a3|


    | a1b1 a1b2 a1b3 |
M = | a2b1 a2b2 a2b3 |
    | a3b1 a3b2 a3b3 |
```

Which is the fastest algorithm to do this task?

More in detail: I need to accomplish this work using the 8086 instruction set, but here I'd prefer to receive the algorithm in C code.

Comment: good question. but what have you tried?

Comment: Also, is there anything about the data that you can guarantee to help shortcut some calculations? (i.e. if it's a typical 2d rotation/scale/translation matrix, there are some 1s and 0s that would be trivial to optimize away)

Comment: Why don't you just do the obvious thing? AFAIK the 8086 doesn't have any cache to speak of, so the usual motivation for any non-obvious way (better use of the cache) does not apply.

Comment: Is this something you can use a library for, or is this some kind of exercise so you need to do it yourself?

Comment: @MOHAMED I tried using the simple for loop O(n^2)...

Comment: @BrianCampbell I can't use any library.

Comment: @gliderkite And was the simple for loop too slow? You are never going to be able to do better than O(n^2), but there may be some ways you can reduce the constants, especially if you know things like the size of the vectors up front. How big are these vectors? By the way, this type of multiplication is generally known as the outer product of two vectors.

Comment: share what you have tried

Comment: @BrianCampbell It isn't too slow, I'm asking here to know if there's a better way.

Comment: @gliderkite Not in general, unless you know something specific about the structure of the two vectors. If you know their length you can do some loop unrolling, which may be faster (always test, since loop unrolling can sometimes make your code slower as well). If they are sparse (contain lots of zeroes), there may be some other tricks you can play to avoid trying a lot of the pointless multiplications. But if they are just two arbitrary vectors and you need to take the outer product, the obvious O(n^2) algorithm is pretty much the best you'll be able to do.

Comment: the way you edited the matrix multiplication is wron. the way you mentioned does not return matrix. it returns only one number

Comment: M31 * M13 ==> M33 and M13 * M31 ==> M11.  Mnk: Matrix with n lines and k columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Matrix Multiplication Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)
To be more precise, I think you are looking for an [efficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) way.

General way of mutliplying matrices is O(n^3), but with efficient way, you will get O(n^2.807). Is it worth your time to implement the efficient way? I don't know, but you will have to assess it.

If you only will have 1D arrays, then the only way is double for loop, in which case, you are looking at run time O(n^2). 
It shouldn't be that complicated to come up with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < B.length; j++)
    {
        C[i][j] = A[i] * B[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is more efficient to invert the j and i indices: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/ (the page is for c++ but the same is true for c) it doesn't matter for the A and B arrays, but it does for the C one, at least when the A and B length grow large.

Comment: @Sebastien, No, it's fine the way it is - the internal loop will traverse `C` column-wise which means contiguous memory locations, exhibiting spatial locality and getting better performance on most modern caches and prefetchers

Comment: I thought it was the other way around. Have checked my link? It seems to suggest that memory is contiguous in rows. Beside, one may avoid the issue entirely by using macro-defined vector-to-array calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Look into BLAS and LAPACK. These are highly optimized.  Don't reinvent the wheel unless you have some reason to avoid libraries. Both of these have C APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably for such simple 3x3 case and with compiler optimization the simplest `O(N^2)` algorithm will be fast enough. If somebody wants to benchmark, you are more than welcome:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lean_and_mean_mul(int a[3], int b[3], int out[3][3])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            out[i][j] = a[i] * b[j];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int b[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int out[3][3];
    lean_and_mean_mul(a, b, out);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", out[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let's peek the assembly of `lean_and_mean_mul()` generated by `gcc -O2 -S`:

```
    xorl    %eax, %eax         
.L2:
    movl    (%rsi), %ecx
    imull   (%rdi), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rdx,%rax)
    movl    4(%rsi), %ecx
    imull   (%rdi), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, 4(%rdx,%rax)
    movl    8(%rsi), %ecx
    imull   (%rdi), %ecx
    addq    $4, %rdi
    movl    %ecx, 8(%rdx,%rax)
    addq    $12, %rax
    cmpq    $36, %rax
    jne .L2
    rep
    ret
```

Notice that compiler decided to [unroll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) one loop.

With `gcc -O3` compiler unrolled both of the loops. [Code](http://pastebin.com/ZYhkz2gc). It's really fast, since it has no jumps at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are big and you want to multiply them as fast as possible, then you should take a look at the [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) library.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to write your code in the simplest/dumbest way (using 2 fors and if/else), in order to let your compiler decide which optimizations can/cannot be done (don't forget to set the flags to -O3). This is better than trying to optimize code by trying to optimize cache/memory accesses by reversing matrix accesses and so on. If you wanna go for an real optimization, find a better algorithm, otherwise code it simple.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Wikipedia article on Matrix Multiplication**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) tells you everything you need.

In this case, you won't get any faster than ***O(n^2)***.

In the general case, the best performance of matrix multiplication is ***O(n ^log2(7))***
(which is approximately ***O(n^2.8)***)

Comment: Man its O(n^3) naive matrix multiplication, and the Divide and Conquer approach has that O(n^2.8), there is a better algorithm which is O(n^2.3) approx, but is not "practically" the best, as stated there are no matrix big enough or enough computing power to handle those matrix for this algorithm to be efficient (damn constants)